# Why can't I scrape all data?

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

with this flow I'm trying to scrape all data from a specific website. The main issue is related to the output of the flow because I'm not receiving the list of all home teams but only the name of home team from the first match. What can I do to receive all data fomr the website?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Lorenzo\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.diretta.it')
html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
games = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'event__match event__match--live event__match--last 
event__match--twoLine')
for game in games:
home = soup.find('div', class_ = 'event__participant event__participant--home').text
away = soup.find('div', class_ = 'event__participant event__participant--away').text
time = soup.find('div', class_ = 'event__time').text
print(home)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when using *selenium* you don't need *beautiful soup*, because you can use `find_elenet_by` to find a tag and `find_elements_by` (**elements with an *s*. Plural**), to get a list of all tags with with similar entities.

Your code would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Lorenzo\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.diretta.it')

games = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class = "event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine"]')

for game in games:
    home = game.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class = "event__participant event__participant--home"]').text
    away = game.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class = "event__participant event__participant--away"]').text
    time = game.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class = "event__time"]').text
    
    print(home)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying with this one importing By  
`games = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class = "event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine"]')

for game in games:
    home = game.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "event__participant event__participant--home"]').text` but i receive as error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: You got that error becaue you wrote `home = game.find_elements` (**Elements** with an **__s__**), this will create a **`list`** and store it in `home`. change `find_elements` to **`find_element`** (Singular element without an **s**). Now it'll work

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now I'm receiving a blank output

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over games but not using it as object for your in-loop finds.

```
home = game.find('div', class_ = 'event__participant event__participant--home').text
```

Comment: Hi, if I paste this line instead of "home = soup.find('div', class_ = 'event__participant event__participant--home').text" I still receive as output only the first element, not all of them